# Why are my Lucene Document results empty?

Tags: lucene, cassandra

I'm running a simple test--trying to index something and then search for it. I index a simple document, but then when a search for a string in it, I get back what looks to be an empty document (it has no fields). Lucene seems to be doing something, because if I search for a word that's not in the document, it returns 0 results.

Any reason why Lucene would reliably return a document when it finds one that matches the given query, and yet that document has nothing in it?

More details:

- I'm actually running Lucandra (Lucene + Cassandra). That certainly may be a relevant detail, but not sure.
- The fields are set to Field.Store/YES and Field.Index/ANALYZED
- Interestingly, I'm able to get this to work just fine on my local machine, but when we put it on our main server (which is a multi-node cassandra setup), I get the behavior described above. So this seems like probably *the* relevant detail, but unfortunately, I see no error message to clue me in to what specifically is causing it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the strings you are storing and how you are querying them? You are probably using QueryParser and not constructing the queries manually?

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if this will work with Lucandra, but you have tried opening the index using Luke? Viewing the index contents with [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) might help

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the problem is since you only provide a very abstract description. However, it sounds a bit like you are not storing the field value in the index. There are different modes for indexing a field. One option determines whether the original value is stored in the index to retrieve it later:

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Store.html

See also the description of the enclosing class `Field`

Comment: Thanks, I realize I only gave an abstract description. And that's because this is implemented in a clojure wrapper around Lucandra which is a way of using Lucene with Clojure.

As for the field store, unfortunately I am using Field.Store/YES so that's not the problem. I'll update the original question now, however, with this and some other information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read: http://anismiles.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/lucandra-an-inside-story/